# Adding inherited items to same list container

Tags: c#, list, oop

Guys I am not sure whether I am missing any important OOP concepts, Please guide me If I am missing something.
I have a base class and some inherited classes as below

```
Class Shape {}
Class Arc:Shape{}
Class Line:Shape{}
```

Now I would like to make a container (List) of all the generated shapes, then when I read back I will cast the  objects to make certain type. What is the best way to do it.Is generics is the only way as I shown below? Please help

```
SortedList shapeList;
public int addShapes(Shape item)  {shapeList.Add(ItemID, item);}
```

Comment: The point of a generic container and OOP is that you don't need to cast the objects back because the objects' behaviour changes based on their actual class, even when called through a base class reference.

Comment: "Is generics is the only way as I shown below" - you haven't shown any use of generics. Note that `SortedList<,>` is really a key/value map, too... if you just want a list, why not use `List<T>`?

Comment: Your container should be `List<Shape>` or another, already existing generic container.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Yes you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put all your `Shape` instances in a `List<Shape>`:

```
var list = new List<Shape>();
list.Add(new Arc());
list.Add(new Line());
list.Add(new Arc());
list.Add(new Arc());
list.Add(new Line());
```

To get all the `Arc` instances, you can do this:

```
var arcs = list.OfType<Arc>();
```

and similarly, for all the `Line` instances:

```
var lines = list.OfType<Line>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your objects to a `List<Shape>`:

```
var list = new List<Shape>();
list.Add(new Arc());
list.add(new Line());
list.Add(new Arc());
```

and then use LINQ to query the original list and retrieve your objects:

```
var arcList = list.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Arc)).ToList();
```

Comment: +0 What's wrong with `.OfType` like in Mark's answer?

Comment: @RubenBartelink At first I didn't notice the method OfType() in the related MSDN documentation. It was something I didn't know. I suppose what Mark proposed does the same job, comparing my LINQ query. I think mine is a valid alternative.

Comment: While it's a perfectly fine answer, it was added adter the first one and isn't different in any useful way. I personally would either delete the answer or edit it to actually add something useful to the conversation. For me, `.OfType` is a far better default (being ~= `as`) rather than doing exact type checks. Unless you think it's really relevant to the OP's question, the combination of being bad advice yet also being a duplicate *almost* pushes me to -1.